# Efficiently tell my height in the Underworld

Tags: terraria-mobile

I'm preparing to battle the [Wall of Flesh](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wall_of_Flesh), but am unable to tell my height in Underworld easily without the possible need of counting blocks.

So, is there a more efficient way of telling my height in the Underworld(And possibly anywhere else) than counting blocks?

Comment: Good luck on killing him!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "height" you meant "depth", i.e your vertical position in the world, there are two items that show depth:

- [Depth Meter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Depth_Meter) - As of version 1.2 found as a **rare drop from Cave Bats** (bugged and doesn't show depth when equipped in mobile version, according to gamepedia and wikia)
- [GPS](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/GPS) - crafted with [Depth Meter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Depth_Meter), [Compass](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Compass) and a [Gold Watch](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gold_Watch) at [Tinkerer's Workshop](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tinkerer%27s_Workshop) in **Hard Mode**

Comment: I am unable to craft either one of these devices, for some reason

Comment: It's only craftable in console versions and a drop-only item in the PC version. I can't find any information if it's a drop or craftable in mobile version...

Comment: As of version 1.2 it's not craftable and is and now a rare drop from cave bats.

Comment: @RavenM You won't be able to craft the GPS without the Hard Mode mats. Both items are available in mobile, though the wiki lists a bug that the Depth Meter does not show your depth in mobile (aka useless).